# unregistering com dll in custom actions of installshield project

Tags: deployment, windows-installer, installshield, setup-deployment

I am using MSVS 2015, and creating an installshield (limited edition) project to package my program files along with a COM dll. I could register the dll but I don't know how to unregister it during uninstallation. Where can I insert the unregistering code in which custom action of the project ?

In Item/step 5 (Define Setup Requirements and Actions), there is Custom Actions During Uninstallation of Custom Actions item but actions in After System Changes are futile because the dll I want to unregister is already gone before the code is executed.

Comment: is it a shared dll, or only used in your app? If shared, you need to recognize the reference count.

Comment: No, it is only used in my application

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need to register your dll during installation and un-register during uninstall, just mark your dll as "self registered" and MSI will take care of automatic registration/un-register at the proper time.

Sure enough, you are able to register and un-register your DLL manually with Custom Action. In this case schedule your CAs:

- for registration somewhere after "InstallFiles" for example right after "SelfRegModules"
- for un-register somewhere after "InstallInitialize" for example right after "SelfUnregModules"